# What does white hole look like on a graph paper?

Tags: black-holes, visualization, white-holes

Like a black hole looks like this, what does a white hole looks like?

[image]

The reason I ask is because I would've imagined that it would look like the exact opposite, i.e. piercing out upwards. But it seems it's the same as black hole in the regards that it also has a mass, so.. I'm slightly confused, how does an "opposite" of black hole look like on graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look exactly the same. Your images are called an "embedding" diagram (or at least, an artist's impression of one...). They visualise the curvature of spacetime near a black hole, by drawing a surface in ordinary Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$ with the same curvature. The classic is "Flamm's paraboloid" -- you can look it up.

Now the choice to orient the funnel this way is purely aesthetics: it points 'downwards', and resembles the traditional gravitational "potential well" from Newton's gravity. But we could flip the surface upside down and its curvature would be exactly the same. That is, you could also draw a black hole as an upside-down funnel. But a white hole has the same curvature as a (same-sized) black hole. And so its embedding diagram(s) are identical.